# How to forbid default user from viewing a database in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I want to restrict the default user from reading tables from a particular database but the revoke command gives following exception.

```
REVOKE SELECT ON test_db.* FROM default

Received exception from server (version 20.5.2):
Code: 495. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Cannot update user `default` in [users.xml] because this storage is readonly.
```

**users.xml has 666 permission**. I am wondering how can this be done, so that default user can not view tables in the given database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to manage users. The old XML-way and the new create/grant/RBAC.

User default is created by old-XML-way (hardcoded in clickhouse source code)

You can remove this user "default" completely.

```
cat /etc/clickhouse-server/conf.d/z_user_def_remove.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<yandex>
    <users>
        <default remove="remove"></default>
    </users>
</yandex>
```

**I named the file with z_ to apply it the end (as the last one).**

Or you can restrict databases for this user "default".

```
cat /etc/clickhouse-server/conf.d/user_def_db.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<yandex>
    <users>
        <default>
           <allow_databases>
            <database>system</database>
           </allow_databases>
        </default>
    </users>
</yandex>
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on the fact that used the default settings for [default-profile](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings/#default-profile) and [inter-server credentials](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings/#server-settings-interserver-http-credentials).

---

I am not sure that *default* user should be modified and be accessible outside of the cluster. By default, it has special purposes such as [interserver interaction in a cluster](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/distributed/).

I would recommend restricting *default* user for using inside cluster nodes:

```xml
<!-- users.xml -->
..
    <profiles>
        <default>
            <!-- default-profile is full-access profile (like super user).
            Do NOT restrict permissions of default-profile. The default profile has a special purpose: it must always be present
            and is applied when starting the server and used by internal processes (Buffer storage, Distibuted DDL worker and so on)
            -->
            ..
        </default>
        ..
    </profiles>

    <users>
        <!--
            default user that used ONLY for inter-server interaction.
            Password intentionally is EMPTY so this account MUST be restricted only inner network.
        -->
        <default>
            <password replace="replace"></password>
            <profile replace="replace">default</profile>

            <networks replace="replace">
                <!-- Restrict account to hosts belonging to the cluster. -->
                <host>clickhouse-node-1</host>
                <host>clickhouse-node-2</host>
                ..
            </networks>
        </default>
        ..
    </users>
..
```

And add a [dedicated users](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/access-rights/) for your goals instead of using *default* one.

Comment: All of that is not true. check interserver_http_credentials & ` <system_profile>default</system_profile>`

Comment: @DennyCrane I suppose that used the default settings and neither default-profile or default inter-server credentials not rewritten. I added the related warning to the answer to not confused readers. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: OK. It's more complicated. Replication does not use default user. It works without by default auth / empty user / empty pass. It does not related to CH internal users.

Comment: Distributed tables use cluster configuration from remote_servers and by default it uses user default but it easy to change.